Limit execution number of bash script triggered by snmp trap
When a trap arrives to my system I execute a bash script automatically. Problem is sometimes a lot of traps arrive simultaneously making a lot executions of the script and generating system cpu pikes
Do you know how could avoid that situation? I thought some mechanism that only executes a determined scripts and the rest waiting like a FIFO queue but I don’t know if that is possible
Thanks

It is a possible solution that would prevent multiple executions of a script at the same time.
First, you would define a fifo:
mkfifo /some/directory/fifo

Then, you would create a script that reads the fifo:
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /some/directory/fifo | while read line ; do
    process "$line"
done

When a trap arrives, you execute the following script:
#!/bin/bash
echo "something from the trap" > /some/directory/fifo

The script that posts the message on the fifo is lightweight and would therefore produce less of a spike than the whole processing. The processing is now serialized, so only one processing script runs at a given time.  You can also nice the processing to give it even less impact.
The echo should be atomic enough to prevent interleaved lines most of the time.
Another option is to use a lock to prevent multiple copies to execute at the same time. That would look like:
#!/bin/bash
me=$$
echo $me>>lockfile
lockedby=$(head -1 lockfile)
while [ "$me" != "$lockedby" ] ; do
    sleep 1
    echo $me>>lockfile
    lockedby=$(head -1 lockfile)
done

process the trap

rm -f lockfile


Wooo thanks for your wonderfoul answer. It seems not working. In script with the comand tail it says me: ./procesa.sh
./procesa.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token do' ./procesa.sh: line 7: tail -f /controlm921/fifo | read line; do'

oops. A while was missing. Sorry.

Many thanks for your help. My problem is there are many concurrents traps and server  freezes, with these method I think I don't have any problem. Maybe the script that I need to execute with every trap will do slow the script results because it should go one by one. But best that that system freeze.

Hi agian. Whith the daemon of while true, the cpu is at 100%. I tried to put in while true a sleep of 3 seconds and CPU has decreased. Do you know if with these fix, always get all traps of fifo file? Thanks

I don't understand what you mean with the "daemon while true". If you mean the second version, then, yes all traps should be processed.

Sorry I’ve explained very bad. I mean with method tail -f. Anyway. Won’t be better with regular file than FIFO file? Thanks

The advantages of a fifo versus a regular file are that a fifo does not use disk and is therefore faster and you don't need to clean up. When you use a regular file, the file just fills up.
